# How do I conditionally load a png or a svg image?

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

We have two sprite images (svg and png) and one compressed CSS file. The compressed CSS files are added to the page as a library (see below) in our sub theme. Default behavior is to always load the sprite-svg CSS class on page load and use the Drupal Behavior to swap the sprite-svg CSS class with the sprite-png CSS class if the Browser is IE.

Are there any modules or alternatives to achieving the same functionality?

mytheme.info.yml (simplified version)

```
name: mytheme
type: theme
base theme: classy
package: Custom
core: 8.x
libraries:
  - netscout/sprite-css
```

mytheme.libraries.yml

```
sprite-css:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/sprite-png.css
      css/sprite-svg.css
  js:
    js/sprite.js
```

sprite-png.css

```
.sprite-png {
  background-image: url('path/to/sprite.png');
}
```

sprite-svg.css

```
.sprite-svg {
  background-image: url('path/to/spring.svg');
}
```

sprite.js

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.loadSpriteImage = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
      var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE");
      if(msie > 0) {
        // If IE, then load PNG CSS class.
        $("body").switchClass("sprite-svg", "sprite-png");
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I think the way you're doing is fine. Your other option is to basically do the same type of check in PHP. The plus side  to that is it will load the correct image the first time. There is a module called browscap that gives you some info on what browser the user is on, however, you could probably just search for a generic PHP function that can tell you if it is IE or not and you could just put that logic in your .theme file using hook_preprocess_html

Comment: @Ronnie I believe you are referring to get_browser() using in PHP, http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php. The `hook_preprocess_html` is not a bad idea, let me try it to see if that works better.

Comment: AFAIK `get_browser()` isn't the best option. Looking at the comments on php.net, https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser is a pretty good alternative and you can easily install it with composer